# Wipe last 1MB of a Hard drive

Tags: linux, partition

Is there an easy command that I can use to zero out the last 1MB of a hard drive?

For the start of the drive I would `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=1M count=1`.  The `seek` option for dd looks promising, but does someone have an easy way to determine exactly how far I should seek?

I have a hardware RAID appliance, that stores some of the RAID configuration at the end of the drive.  I need the RAID appliance to see the drives as un-configured, so I want to remove the RAID configuration without having to spend the time to do a full wipe of the drives. I have a dozen 2TB drives, and a full erase of all of those drives would take a long time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The simplest way on Linux to get the size of the disk is with `blockdev --getsz`:

```
sudo -s
dd bs=512 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx count=2048 seek=$((`blockdev --getsz /dev/sdx` - 2048))
```

Comment: Excellent, I knew there must be a tool that could get the size easily.

Comment: While I like the solution, using `sda` as example is horribly dangerous if you copy & paste and manage to get the carriage return copied. `sdx` would be much better suited.

I take precautions, but only because of them I didn't destroy my disk right now.

Comment: @emk2203 Good point. I'm curious, what precautions do you have in place for such scenarios?

Comment: I use a single quote before pasting. If the line contains a carriage return, it gets caught by the shell prompt because of the missing end for the quotation. If everything is OK, I go to the start of the line with Ctrl-A, then delete the quote, then return. Three more keystrokes for insurance, worth it.

Comment: Instead of /dev/sdx, look at the links in /dev/disk/by-id/ such as  nvme-SAMSUNG_MZVLW1TXXXX-000XX_XXXXXXXXX.  ls -l  /dev/disk/by-id/ will show the link name and the /dev/sdX it links to.

Answer (score 8):

The size of every partition is available in `/proc/partitions`. The following command shows the size of `sdx` (in kB units):

```
awk '$4 == "sdx" {print $3}' </proc/partitions
```

Thus:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=1k count=1024 \
   seek=$(($(awk '$4 == "sdx" {print $3}' </proc/partitions) - 1024))
```

Comment: What's the reason for the -1024 at the end?

Comment: @Hashim The question asks how to wipe the last 1MB. The last 1MB starts 1024kB before the end.

Answer (score 4):

Using the seek to get to the end of the drive works very well, i.e.:

> seek=$((`blockdev --getsz /dev/sda` - 2048))

However, when you use this, I recommend that you either know that your count value is correct, or not use it at all. The reason I say this is that drives can have either 512 byte sectors or 4k sectors, and if you use this solution with a drive that has 4k sectors on it, you won't go to the end of the drive with that count value, and may miss the RAID information at the end (I have run into this).

Comment: Could you share somehow what exactly you ran into? I am intrigued, wondering if I misunderstood how `dd` adresses sectors when used with custom `bs` values smaller/bigger then the actual blocksize reported by the device's firmware or the linux kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of sectors on the disk with `hdparm -v /dev/sdx`. Try seeking to number_of_sectors - 2048 (assuming 512 byte sectors).

Comment: hdparm seems handy, but how would I check the sector size?

Comment: `/sys/block/sdx/queue/physical_block_size` may give you the information but some newer disks play fast and loose with the sector size they report. It's probably better to read the label on the disk or look it up in the manufacturers data sheet.

Comment: Thanks.. I've just noticed that `hdparm -I /dev/sda` lists 2 "versions" of sector size: `Logical` and `Physical`. Is this what you mean by "fast-and-loose"? .... I jsut get that "feeling" that if anything is going to behave in such a way it could well be a RAID system..

Comment: @red: I can't fid the reference now but I read somewhere that some drives with 4096 byte sectors will report to the system that they are 512byte and then deal wit the conversion internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dd` and get the device size via `fdisk`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1k \
   seek=$(( (`fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep 'Disk /' | cut -d' ' -f 5` -1024*1024)/1024  )) count=1024
```

I am not using a blocksize of 1m to avoid rounding errors.

Alternatively, you could write a small C-program (or script) which invokes the `lseek` function with `SEEK_END` and a negative offset of 1mb and then call `write`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old thread, but I had to clean up some disks which were members of RAID and I came across the same thing. Here is my answer which allows you to easily select the disk and the size (in MB) you want to write (from the end of the drive, of course).

```
disk=/dev/sdX && mb=10 && dd if=/dev/zero of=$disk bs=512 count=$(( 2048 * $mb )) seek=$(( $(blockdev --getsz $disk) - 2048 * $mb ))
```

The example I have given writes 10M at the end of the disk. By simply changing the `mb` variable you choose how many megabytes to write.

Answer (score 0):

Any shell or tool that can call the `lseek()` system call with `SEEK_END` (an offset relative to the end) would do.

In `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/system
{sysseek -w end -u1 -1048576 && sysread -s 1048576 < /dev/zero -o1} > /dev/sdX
```

In `ksh93`:

```
builtin head # in case you system's head doesn't support head -c
head -c 1MiB < /dev/zero 3> /dev/sdX 3>#((EOF - 1048576)) >&3 3>&-
```

Here *not* using `head -c1M` because [it means 1000000 bytes there](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/319), and doing the `lseek()` (with the `>#((offset))` operator) on fd 3 because of [this  bug](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/318).

With `perl`:

```
perl -e 'seek STDOUT,-1048576,2 or die; print "\0" x 1048576' > /dev/sdX
```

With `socat`:

```
head -c1M < /dev/zero | socat -u - file:/dev/sdX,seek-end=-1048576
```